# How to convert long value to date using adf el expression?

Tags: oracle-adf

I am using an ADF application. I have stored the date value in long format in my database.
I am using the input date format.
my coding is given bellow

```
<af:inputDate label="Label 1" id="id1" value="#{pageFlowScope.TestBean.date}"/>
```

I want to convert the long value to date format using El expression if it's possible to convert long to date using all expression?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the af:convertDateTime component.
Or you could set the date format directly in your VO (if your attribute is mapped to Timestamp).

Answer (score 0):

In the back bean, you should have a Date variable ready already, you could use new Date(your_long_value_variable) to create a Date object. Then bind the date object with the value of your inputText/outputText, then use the af:convertDateTime to convert the format. For example:

```
<af:outputText value="#{your_date_variable}"
               id="example1">
  <af:convertDateTime type="both"
                      timeZone="GMT"/>
</af:outputText>
```

The type attribute specifies what contents the string value will be formatted to include, or parsed. Valid values are "date", "time", and "both". Default value is "date".

And timezone attribute is in which timezone to interpret any time information in the date string. And you can also edit the pattern attribute to decide the date format.

You could also modify the "pattern" attribute to change the format.

Plus, http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/apirefs.1111/e12419/tagdoc/af_convertDateTime.html is the link for the af:convertDateTime.